# What is the difference between "List names" and "List<String> names" in Dart?

Tags: dart

What is the difference between the following two statements:

```
List names = ["John", "Robert", "James"];

List<String> names = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart will in the first example assume the type should be `List<dynamic>` since you have just told the type system that you want a `List` without any specific restrictions.

In the second example, the created list are getting the type `List<String>` since you have provided a restriction of the type of elements you want in the list.

Another example would be the following:

```dart
var names = ["John", "Robert", "James"]; // or final instead of var
```

Here we are letting Dart automatically determine the most restrictive type possible. In this case, the `names` are going to be automatically typed `List<String>`.

You can see this if you print the `runtimeType` of each declared list:

```dart
void main() {
  List names1 = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
  print(names1.runtimeType); // List<dynamic>
  
  List<String> names2 = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
  print(names2.runtimeType); // List<String>
  
  var names3 = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
  print(names3.runtimeType); // List<String>
}
```